# What is the reasoning behind this step in the proof of $\lim_{x \to a^- }F_X(x)= P(X\lt a)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have two questions about the reasoning behind the steps in the following proof:

Suppose $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X.$
Then $$\lim_{x\to a^-}F_X(x)=P(X \lt x)$$

Proof:(written a bit informally)

Suppose $F_X$ is the CDF of a random variable $X$

$F_X $ being a CDF $\implies$

$$\implies F_X \text{ is monotonic increasing} \tag 1 $$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to a^-}F_X(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}F_X \left(a- \frac{1}{n}\right) \tag 2$$

By definition $F_X(a-\frac{1}{n})=P(E(X\leq a-\frac{1}{n})) \tag 3$

Notice that $E_n= E(X\leq a-\frac{1}{n})$ is an increasing sequence of events so by the lemma

> Lemma: If $E_N$ for $n\geq 1$ is an increasing sequence of events in a probability space and $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$,
>   Then $P(E)=\lim_{n\to \infty}P(E_N)$.

therefore by the lemma:

$$\lim_{x \to a^-}F_X(x)= \lim_{n\to \infty}P\left( E\left(X\leq a-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E\left(X\leq a -\frac{1}{i} \right) \right).$$

However,

\begin{align}
& \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E(X\leq a -\frac{1}{i}) \tag 4 \\[8pt]
= {} & \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \leq a -\frac{1}{i} \space \text{for some } i \geq 1\} \tag 5 \\[8pt]
= {} & \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) < a\} \tag 6 \\[8pt]
= {} & E(X < a)
\end{align}

Thus,
$$\lim_{x\to a^-}F_X(x)=P(E(X < a))=P(X < a)$$

$\square$

My questions are:

1) How does step [1] imply step [2] exactly?

2) Why is is that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E(X\leq a -\frac{1}{i})$

$$=\{\omega \in \Omega: X(w) \leq a -\frac{1}{i} \space \text{for some  } i \geq n\}$$

3) How does step [4] imply step [5]??

Comment: I have no idea why you have expectations in this proof. The proof seems overcomplicated as well.

Comment: At the beginning, I think you'd want to use specific continuity properties of the CDF (besides just monotone increasing, e.g., right continuous). That property motivates the $x \to a^{-}$ limit

Comment: @EpsilonDelta $E(X \in A)$ is used to mean $\{ \omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in A \} $ where A is some subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

The way in which $(1)$ implies $(2)$ is by implying that the first limit in $(2)$ exists. Once you have that, the equality in $(2)$ must hold.

Your way of using the capital $E$ is new to me, but if I understand it correctly, the implication from $(4)$ to $(5)$ is merely the definition of "union", provided what you meant in $(5)$ is "for some $i\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}.$" And if you didn't mean that, then there's the question of what the "$n$" is, in step $(5),$ and that is not at all clear. To say that a point is in the union of a certain collection of sets means just that it is a member of at least one of those sets.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your notation and formatting is odd to me, so I will give a complete account of the proof that hopefully clears up the details:

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable with CDF $F_X$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. We have
$$\bigcup_{n\ge0}\left\{\omega\in\Omega\colon X(\omega)\le a-\frac{1}{n}\right\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\colon X(\omega)<a\}.$$
If $\omega\in\Omega$ is such that $X(\omega)\le a-\frac{1}{n}$, then $X(\omega)\le a-\frac{1}{n}<a$, so the inclusion "$\subseteq$" is clear. If, on the other hand, $\omega\in\Omega$ is such that $X(\omega)<a$, note that $X(\omega)<a-\frac{a-X(\omega)}{2}\le a-\frac{1}{n}$ for $n=\left\lceil\frac{2}{a-X(\omega)}\right\rceil$, so the reverse inclusion holds too. Alternatively, one could argue that if $X(\omega)>a-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\ge0$, then, by taking the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $X(\omega)\ge a$, which also proves the reverse inclusion by contraposition. Now, since $F_X$ is monotone, the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}F_X(x)$ exists. Therefore, and by invoking the lemma, we have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}F_X(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_X\left(a-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(X\le a-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\mathbb{P}(X<a).$$